# LLVM JIT cannot find symbol '___chkstk_ms'

Tags: c++, llvm, mingw-w64, llvm-ir

I'm toying around with LLVM using the C++ API, and I've built the following program:

```
  %allocArr = alloca ptr, i32 2, align 8
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds ptr, ptr %allocArr, i32 0
  store ptr @internalString, ptr %4, align 8
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds ptr, ptr %allocArr, i32 1
  store ptr @internalString.1, ptr %5, align 8
  call void @runtimeErr(ptr @internalString.2, ptr %allocArr, i32 2)
  call void @print(i64 %3)
  ret void
```

However when I try to execute it using the JIT engine from the [Kaleidoscope tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/BuildingAJIT1.html) I get the following error

```
JIT session error: Symbols not found: [ ___chkstk_ms ]
Failed to materialize symbols: { (<main>, { anon }) } // anon is the name of my function
```

After some prodding on google I found out that `___chkstk_ms` is a runtime function and is provided by libgcc, I built LLVM from scratch and am using MinGW ver. 11.0.0. with GCC 13.1.0 and there is indeed a libgcc_s.a file in the /lib folder of mingw. So it is there, but for some reason the JIT can't find it.

Comment: `__chkstk_ms` is part of GCC's stack protection, so it looks like your LLVM depends on GCC's stack protection somehow. When building LLVM and its dependencies with GCC try specifying `-fno-stack-protector`.

Comment: @BrechtSanders I see, will try to do that, in the meantime I've found that simply running the LLVM IR module through a optimization pass seems to remove the call to `__chkstk_ms` so the code does work right now, just not when it's unoptimized. Thanks!